# How to link to a users profile in a view

Tags: views

I created a view which displays users on my site. Using "Rewrite results" I displayed the first name and Surname in one column. I then checked "Output this field as a link".

My challenge is what path will I enter into the "Link Path" field to ensure that the names in the column link to the user profiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, user profiles are at `user/UID`, where `UID` is the numeric user ID.  (This is true unless you are using a module like Pathauto to customize the profile URLs.)

So, one way to do this is to:

1. Add the numeric user ID field to your view.  Make sure to check *exclude from display* so it won't actually be shown in the view.
2. Reorder the fields in the view so that the *user ID* field comes before the field for which you want to rewrite results.
3. The value of the *user ID* field will now be available as a token in "Rewrite results."  So, you can use the token to create a link to the user profile like this: `user/[uid]` (the actual token may be slightly different).